NSFetchedResultsController with == predicate not updating with new object
I have a VC that displays a game level and its progress (let's call it LevelProgress with an "levelId" attribute). This LevelProgress doesn't exist in CoreData unless the user plays for the first time.
The code to fetch this level progress using NSFetchedResultsController is the following:
let gameLevelId: String = "level_10"
let request: NSFetchRequest<LevelProgress> = LevelProgress.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "levelId == %@", gameLevelId)
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: \LevelProgress.createdDate, ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
let resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.manager.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
do {
    try resultsController.performFetch()
    return resultsController
} catch {
    throw error
}

My issue is that at first launch, there is no CoreData LevelProgress object. It's empty and it makes sense. Then the user plays, which generates a new LevelProgress with its levelId.
I expect resultsController.fetchedObjects to have my new object, but it remains empty until I rerun performFetch().
However, NSFetchedResultsController works correctly if there is already an existing LevelProgress. So let's say there is another attribute "nbTimesCompleted", if the user opens the VC for the second time (with an already existing LevelProgress object) then plays again, the resultsController.fetchedObjects will have the LevelProgress nbTimesCompleted attribute correctly updated.
What's the workaround to handle an inserted object with an equality predicate to NSFetchedResultsController?
